# LockFileEx returns success, but seems to have no effect

Tags: windows, file-io, mutex

I'm trying to lock a file, because it is sitting on a network drive, and multiple instances of a program from multiple computers need to edit it. To prevent damage, I intend to set it up so that only one of the instances has rights to it at a time.

I implemented a lock, which would theoretically lock the first 100 bytes of the file from any access. I'm using Qt with its own file handling, but it has a method of returning a generic file handle.

```c++
QFile file(path);
HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(file.handle());
OVERLAPPED ov1;
memset(&ov1, 0, sizeof(ov1));
ov1.Offset = 0;
ov1.OffsetHigh = 0;
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // error
    return;
}

LockFileEx(handle, LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY | LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, 0, 100, 0, &ov1);
qDebug() << file.readLine();
```

`LockFileEx()` returns `1`, so it seems to have been successful. However, if I run the program in multiple instances, all of them can read and print the first line of the file. More than this, I can freely edit the file with any text editor.
Being a network file is not an issue, as it behaves similarly with a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, while the program does not terminate, the `QFile` variable was local, so after finishing the function, the destructor of the `QFile` was called, so it released the file. The OS then seemed to have released the lock.

If my `QFile` survives the scope, everything works just fine. A minor issue is, that while I expected the file to be locked against reading, external programs do have a read-only access to it. It's not a problem, as my program can check whether it can create a lock, and detect failure to do so. This means that the intended mutex functionality works.